# return callback value to main function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This my code. Please help me. Return budget from callbacks how value main function.

How return value main function

```
    //Метод возвращает текущий бюджет пользователя
    getCurrentBudget: function (req) {
        var reqToken = req.headers["authorization"].substr(7);
        var is = true;

        jwt.verify(reqToken, config['jwt'], function (error, user) {
            // Если бюджет текущего пользователя
            if (user.currentBudget) {
                db.budget.findOne({ownerId: objectId(user._id)}, function(error, budget) {
                    if (!error && budget) {
                        //Бюджет найден
                        logger.debug('Бюджет найден: %j', budget, {});
                        return budget;
                    }
                })
            } else {
                // Ищем бюджет в который пригласили этого пользователя
                db.budget.findOne({membersEmail: user.email}, function(error, budget) {
                    if (!error && budget) {
                        //Бюджет найден
                        logger.debug('Бюджет найден: %j', budget, {});
                        return budget;
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: `getCurrentBudget()` should be declared as `var getCurrentBudget = function(){...};` for starters.

Comment: Impossible. The main function exists long before the callback is invoked. Do a search and you'll find hundreds of other questions asking how to return a value from a callback or from an AJAX request. The solutions there will be helpful. Basically you don't return the data to the code, you bring to code to the data.

Comment: You could also use a promise framework/library (such as q, see https://github.com/kriskowal/q), to make the code more robust. Either way, you need to use callback functions as suggested in the answers below, since you are dealing with asynchronous JavaScript here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call asynchronous code from your function you need to provide callback to "return" result. For example:

```
getCurrentBudget: function (req, callback) {
    var reqToken = req.headers["authorization"].substr(7);
    var is = true;

    jwt.verify(reqToken, config['jwt'], function (error, user) {
        // Если бюджет текущего пользователя
        if (user.currentBudget) {
            db.budget.findOne({ownerId: objectId(user._id)}, function(error, budget) {
                if (!error && budget) {
                    //Бюджет найден
                    logger.debug('Бюджет найден: %j', budget, {});
                    callback(budget);
                }
            })
        } else {
            // Ищем бюджет в который пригласили этого пользователя
            db.budget.findOne({membersEmail: user.email}, function(error, budget) {
                if (!error && budget) {
                    //Бюджет найден
                    logger.debug('Бюджет найден: %j', budget, {});
                    callback(budget);
                }
            })
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это решение подошло!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getCurrentBudget: function (req, callback) { // callback is a function to get budget
    var reqToken = req.headers["authorization"].substr(7);
    var is = true;

    jwt.verify(reqToken, config['jwt'], function (error, user) {
        // Если бюджет текущего пользователя
        if (user.currentBudget) {
            db.budget.findOne({ownerId: objectId(user._id)}, function(error, budget) {
                if (!error && budget) {
                    //Бюджет найден
                    logger.debug('Бюджет найден: %j', budget, {});
                    callback(budget);
                }
            })
        } else {
            // Ищем бюджет в который пригласили этого пользователя
            db.budget.findOne({membersEmail: user.email}, function(error, budget) {
                if (!error && budget) {
                    //Бюджет найден
                    logger.debug('Бюджет найден: %j', budget, {});
                    callback(budget);
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

And in your main, you call this method like this:

main function() {

```
  getCurrentBudget(req, function(budget) { // this function is your callback actually
     console.log(budget);
  });
}
```